# evaluateJavaScript on WKWebView running slow

Tags: wkwebview

Running evaluateJavaScript on a WKWebView to inject a JS script can take quite some time to run on a device.

The JS script is quite complex, but is is normal for evaluateJavascript to take 20-30 seconds to run?

Comment: did find a solution?

Comment: Same here. Did you find any Workaround?